# Wikipedia API and SPARQL in a single query

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I need to search for Wikipedia pages that contain some specific words in their **full text**. To improve the results I want to limit the results to pages describing entities that are **instances of** a specific entity.

For searching the full text I can use the Wikipedia APIs, using the *query action* and the *search generator*.

For filtering instances of a given entity I can use the Wikidata APIs and a SPARQL query.

Is there a way to execute both operations in a single query that applies both filters?

Answer (score 4):

Since [June 2017](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T148245), it is [possible](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI) to call out to Wikimedia APIs from Wikidata SPARQL:

```sql
SELECT ?wikidata_item ?wikipedia_title {
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "search" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:gsrsearch "triplestore" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:gsrlimit "max" .
      ?wikidata_item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item . 
      ?wikipedia_title wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title .
 }
  # hint:Prior hint:runFirst "true".
  ?wikidata_item wdt:P31 wd:Q3539533  .
  FILTER (?wikipedia_title != "Blazegraph")
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fwikidata_item%20%3Fwikipedia_title%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22en.wikipedia.org%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22Generator%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Agenerator%20%22search%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Agsrsearch%20%22triplestore%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Agsrlimit%20%22max%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwikidata_item%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Aitem%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_title%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Atitle%20.%0A%20%7D%0A%20%23%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunFirst%20%22true%22.%0A%20%20%3Fwikidata_item%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3539533%20%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fwikipedia_title%20%21%3D%20%22Blazegraph%22%29%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2):

No, those have completely separate search backends that do not interact. The Wikidata API uses SQL queries; the search API uses Elasticsearch; the SPARQL service uses Blazegraph.