# Wikidata SPARQL extract ranked items from alias query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to query a string "Merkel".

I want the output to be something like:

```
  ID         instance_of   LABEL          
 ---------- ------------- --------------- 
  Q567       Q5            Angela Merkel  
  Q1921787   Q101352       Merkel         
  Q969485    Q1093829      Merkel
```

This is what I have until now. [Click here to see on WIkidata Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Finstance_of%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%3Flabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Flabel%20%22Merkel%22%40de.%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Finstance_of.%20%7D%0A%7D)

```sql
SELECT ?instance_of ?s ?p ?o ?label WHERE {
?s ?label "Merkel"@de.
?s ?p ?o
OPTIONAL { ?s wdt:P31 ?instance_of. }}
```

I want the search results to be ranked, most popular/relevant to least relevant. I have no clue on how to do that.

On the Wikidata website, they do it when you search for a term, perhaps a order by statements and sitelinks is a possible solution.

Comment: you need some kind of ranking measure first in the dataset

Comment: Well, and indeed this was already asked before (with a great answer by the way): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438022/wikidata-results-sorted-by-something-similar-to-a-pagerank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wikidata results sorted by something similar to a PageRank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438022/wikidata-results-sorted-by-something-similar-to-a-pagerank)

Comment: I am looking for items in the alias. At this point ranked by the number of sitelinks will do.

Comment: Ok, then just reuse the query in the answer I referred to. Or does it not work?

Comment: How do I combine "rank by" with "search in alias"?The stuff from the link you mentioned does not work.

Comment: What? Works as expected, e.g. ordered by incoming links: `SELECT ?s ?instance_of  WHERE {
  ?s rdfs:label "Merkel"@de.
  ?s wdt:P31 ?instance_of.
  
  
      {
       SELECT (count(?s) AS ?incoming) (?item as ?s) WHERE {
           ?item rdfs:label "Merkel"@de.
           ?s ?p ?item .
           [] wikibase:directClaim ?p 
      } GROUP BY ?item
                 }
} ORDER BY DESC (?incoming)`

Comment: Is there a way to implement a fuzzy match to the keyword, something like:´´´FILTER (CONTAINS(LCASE(STR(?label)), "Merkel"))´´´, because now the query only searches for an item that exactly matches the query.

Comment: well, either the `filter(contains(...` as in your comment or `filter(regex(...` - indeed both might fail due to timeout given that we don`t have any fulltext index, thus, have to scan over the whole dataset

Comment: Where exactly do I put it in the above query? I keep getting a ``"Query is malformed: Encountered " "filter""`` error

Comment: just put the filter expression inside the inner SELECT and the out SELECT. and indeed don't forget to replace `"Merkel"@de` with `?label`

Comment: Full-text search is another interesting question... If you just need a ready-to-use query that gives results ordered as in the Wikidata search page (and not as in the autosuggestions), you can use Wikidata API. It is possible to call out this API from SPARQL. https://pastebin.com/DDExvaGP

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin Thanks! This exactly what I wanted. Could you put your answer below, then I can accept it.

Comment: @Pagamas, thank you. You could better upvote this community wiki answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310764/7879193 :-) BTW, it seems that the Wikidata full-text search API is slower than the Wikipedia one.

Comment: yes, it's going to take ages

Comment: @pajamas, there are undocumented tricks: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T177275#4631207